# Xamarin Android crash when starting application

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

In my most recent build, the google play console is sending this stack trace pretty often. I haven't seen it in the past. I was wondering if anyone has seen this before and might know what's causing the issue.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3762)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3938)
  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:135)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:95)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2277)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:246)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8425)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:596)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1130)
Caused by: androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: 
  at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.instantiate (Fragment.java:628)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainer.instantiate (FragmentContainer.java:57)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$3.instantiate (FragmentManager.java:483)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.<init> (FragmentStateManager.java:85)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.restoreSaveState (FragmentManager.java:2714)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.restoreSaveState (FragmentController.java:198)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity$2.onContextAvailable (FragmentActivity.java:149)
  at androidx.activity.contextaware.ContextAwareHelper.dispatchOnContextAvailable (ContextAwareHelper.java:99)
  at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.onCreate (ComponentActivity.java:307)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate (FragmentActivity.java:269)
  at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate (AppCompatActivity.java:115)
  at crc647afa4e63b6630bdc.MainActivity.n_onCreate (Native Method)
  at crc647afa4e63b6630bdc.MainActivity.onCreate (MainActivity.java:38)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:8183)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:8167)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1309)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3735)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: 
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0 (Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance (Constructor.java:343)
  at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.instantiate (Fragment.java:610)
  at Caused
  at Java.Interop.TypeManager.n_Activate
  at mono.android.TypeManager.n_activate (Native Method)
  at mono.android.TypeManager.Activate (TypeManager.java:7)
  at crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.ShellItemRenderer.<init> (ShellItemRenderer.java:26)
```

I wish this stack trace was more descriptive. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you update the IDE or the version of XF recently ? If yes, you could delete the folder `bin` and `obj` both in share and Android project , then clean and rebuild it .

Comment: Yes, I updated to XF 5.0 recently. I tried deleting and bin and obj folders in the project and releasing a new build. Unfortunately, still getting the error.

Comment: As you can see it crashes inside ShellItemRenderer, so might fill a xamarin bug report.